# Отключается бот на Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, бот, pythonanywhere

Есть телеграм бот на python. Протестирован, все работает, ошибок не выдает. Захостил на Pythonanywhere и бот отключается в рандомное время. Открываю консоль где должен работать код, а она начинает грузится заново и он уже отключен. У меня платный аккаунт за 5$ если это имеет значение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так происходит из-за перезагрузки серверов Pythonanywhere.

На платном аккаунте можно использовать Always-on tasks
Чтобы настроить постоянную задачу, вам просто нужно ввести полную команду, чтобы запустить ее в поле ввода

```
python3.6 /home/yourusername/a-directory/a-script.py
```

Подробное описание https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AlwaysOnTasks